# Provide httpClient to node-soap

Tags: node.js, http, soap, httpclient, node-soap

I am trying to set the `maxSockets` on the request and send this to `node-soap` when creating the client. The transactions work well without this. I tried adding it through the httpAgent but once the `maxSockets` property is added I got a `socket hang up` error. So, my approach now is to try to configure this using the `httpClient` available on the library, however, I haven't been able to do it. Here is my code:

```
//OPTION 1
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
const httpsClient: AxiosInstance = axios.create();
httpsClient.request({
  url: url,
  httpsAgent: httpsAgent,
  timeout: 15000,
});

//OPTION 2
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true });
const httpsClient: AxiosInstance = axios.create();
httpsClient.defaults.httpsAgent = HttpsAgent;
```

This is what the library's documentation says about the httpClient:
`httpClient: to provide your own http client that implements request(url, data, callback, exheaders, exoptions).`

Answer (score 1):

Found out that setting the `keepAlive` property on the HTTP Agent was killing the connection. So I set it up only the `maxSockets` on it and add a header to `node-soap` when creating the client.

`client.addHttpHeader("connection", "keep-alive");`